# namedpipe async read calling without data

Tags: c#, asynchronous, named-pipes, beginread

I am writing a windows service and a separate GUI program and i want them communicating with named pipes. The windows service is the pipe server and the GUI will be the client.

The problem is that when my client connects to the pipeServer my BeginRead async-callback keeps firing. The client hasn't send any data.

```
    const int buffersize= 255;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];

    private void newConnection(IAsyncResult iar) {
       //stop waiting for connection
       pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(iar);

        //register callback
       beginreadResult = server.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffFormaat, newMessage, pipeServer);

    }


    public void newMessage(IAsyncResult r)
    {

            try
            {
                pipeServer.EndRead(beginreadResult);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                System.Environment.Exit(0);
            }
                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("new message: " + message);


            beginreadResult= server.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffersize, newMessage, server);

    }
```

I can't figure out why the newMessage() callback keeps being called, anybody ideas?

Comment: What does `pipeServer.EndRead` return. Is it `<= 0` ?

Comment: `pipeServer.EndRead` returns 0, but why is the callback called if there is no data? Isn't that the point of async reading?

Comment: It clearly says to you *other end closed the connection,there is no more data to read* but you keep on reading...

Comment: What value does `buffFormaat` have? 0?

Comment: Thanks guy's found out my pipe was closed on the client side. This because I used a 'using' block where my stream closed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451429/how-to-continue-sending-reading-messages-from-named-pipes-streams)