# Continuous Communication between C# and Python

Tags: c#, python, sockets, ipc, named-pipes

I'm trying to start a Python script from C#(WinForms) App, with arguments and get values from that script continiously until certain conditions satisfied. Type of data I need to pass is string and rate is like 2 or 1 string per second.

Is NamedPipeline good approach to achieve this goal, or should I go with sockets or is there any other tool that I can use for this purpose.

PS: Both script and App will run in same machine.
PS2: IronPython won't help since it doesn't allow me to use related Python script due to the restrictions.

Comment: What is pipeline? I guess it´s some framework, which pretty sure has nothing to do with the pipeline-tag. Apart from this your question is fairly opinion-based. Questions about frameworks or docus are off-topic on this site. Just try it out and see how far you approach.

Comment: By pipeline I mean this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication
There are some recommendations about using it to provide connection between Python Script and C# App

Comment: In your case I'd also go for a named pipe. It passes strings and is quickly set up.

Comment: @Fildor , sorry fixed.

Comment: @linuxrocks is it good approach for continuous communication ?

Comment: _"is it good approach"_ - It is _one_ approach. I'd suggest you make a little "proof of concept" project and see if it fits your requirements.

Comment: I know a former colleague who did it, so I guess it's possible. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451429/how-to-continue-sending-reading-messages-from-named-pipes-streams) can get you started.

Comment: @Fildor my goal is, I have tracking script(Image processing) that if I run it in C# App, it has serious delay problems. So what I'm trying to do is run the script in Python, return values of RoI to C# app and draw a Rectangle.

Comment: @linuxrocks Thank you for guidance, I'll try and share the results. Have a nice day.